# Update profile properties jsom

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom

I can update my own profile properties but i cant update other users profile properties. When i do i'll get an "you are not authorized.." error. I have administration rights.

Here is my function to write profile properties

```
function writeProfileProperties(accountName, propertyKey){
      var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext); 
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){
       peopleManager.setSingleValueProfileProperty(accountName, propertyKey, "Value updated from JSOM!");
       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){

            alert("properties updated!");
        }, 
        function(sender,args){
            //On Error
            alert(args.get_message());
        });
    }, function(sender,args){
        //On Error
        alert(args.get_message());
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Did you give the app write permissions to user profiles?

Comment: Its not an app. Its a javascript file inside a content editor web part on my sitecollection

Comment: Ah.  Are you an admin of the tenant? If so, try going to the user profile settings, make yourself a site collection admin of another user, and see if that lets you update their properties.  Also, can you update your question with the exact error text?

Comment: Im not an admin as in the name admin i just have administration rights for my test sitecollection. Or what do you mean by admin of the tenant? The exact error message is: "Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."

Comment: Can you access the admin area for your tenant? Would be located at `https://<tenant>-admin.sharepoint.com/`.  So if your tenant is `contoso`, and your url is `https://contoso.sharepoint.com/`, your admin url would be `https://contoso-admin.sharepoint.com/`.

Comment: Yes i can do that

Comment: You might be a SharePoint admin then.  Try to see if you can make yourself a site collection admin of a user profile.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by "site collection admin of a user profile"